# Sitecore: Implementing mapped network drive, and applying rules to the folder structure

Tags: security, sitecore, datasource, roles, provider

How could one go about integrating an "external" mapped network drive, and have the structure relate to some security roles?

The users should only be able to have access (read/write) to files in specific folder/subfolders, as permitted by their roles.

Comment: I would love an example on how to implement the FileSystemDataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the

```
Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.FileSystemDataProvider
```

I haven't used this in a long while, but it essentially allows you to set up a new Sitecore Database (look in Web.config for how the database id="filesystem" is configured).

Once in place, the file system entries (files, directories) would appear to Sitecore as "any regular item" - and could therefore be controlled by Sitecore Security.

You're likely going to need to implement a bespoke extension to the FileSystemDataProvider, as you would need to persist Sitecore data (like for instance the Security Settings).

All in all, sounds like a lot more work than it would probably be worth.

Have you considered WebDAV as an option?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been considering the FileSystemDataProvider, and was particularly looking for a way to use that in conjunction with the security model in SC. Regarding WebDAV, I dont think its a solution, as far as my limited WebDAV knowledge goes, and this solution is to be worked around an already existing network drive used by other instances in the company.